# Count how many times a value in the database has changed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have data, a list of Box IDs like below:

```
boxID     DateTime
-----     --------
001       2021-06-24 00:00:01
001       2021-06-24 00:00:02
001       2021-06-24 00:00:04
001       2021-06-24 00:00:05
001       2021-06-24 00:00:06
911       2021-06-24 00:00:07
911       2021-06-24 00:00:09
911       2021-06-24 00:00:10
001       2021-06-24 00:00:11
001       2021-06-24 00:00:12
100       2021-06-24 00:00:13
100       2021-06-24 00:00:14
001       2021-06-24 00:00:15
911       2021-06-24 00:00:16
911       2021-06-24 00:00:17
```

And I need to count how many times are they used after change the boxID?

My expected return is:

```
boxID     used
-----     -----
001       3
911       2
100       1
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 so I cannot use `LAG()` function.
Is there any other function to help me fixing this case?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How about `select boxID, used=count(*) from BoxList group by boxID` ? Maybe I've misunderstood what you need.

Comment: ahh sorry, I thought it can be done using the specific column only. I also have another column and I have updated my question. Please look at my question again..

Comment: @JohnD thank you for your comment, but i need to count how many time they have been used after the box changed?

Comment: Why are you using unsupported software?

Comment: its in my company as I am not able to change the software. But thanks for your question @Gordon

Comment: @tryingtocode . . . A business should not be using unsupported software.  It is open to attacks that the vendor is not going to help you with resolving.  Very dangerous.  One hopes there is no PII stored in this database!  Sadly, a company that would not take precautions to use supported software probably does not take precautions on what is stored in those systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY boxID ORDER BY DateTime) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT boxID, COUNT(DISTINCT rn1 - rn2) AS used
FROM cte
GROUP BY boxID;
```